# Lists of even numbers and an odd number

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am asked to find the number of lists with $100$ elements subject to two conditions:

1. Numbers chose must be from the set $\{1\cdots 48\}$
2. There must be only one odd number
3. Each even number must appear at least once

   Here is my attempt:

   To begin with, one has to choose which odd number appears: there are $24$ odd numbers in that set. Each one of these possibilities can appear in a total of $100$ positions. The remaining part would be distributing all the even numbers in the set with the condition that eachone appears at least once. There are $99$ positions left. This is the same as distributing $99$ distinguishable balls into $24$ different boxes. It is also the same as the number of surjective applications between a set of $99$ elements and a set of $24$ elements, which is $24!\cdot S(99,24)$. Therefore, using the product rule, there are $24\cdot100 \cdot24! \cdot S(99,24) = 2400 \cdot 24! \cdot S(99,24)$ different possible lists. Is this right?

Comment: I would say it is correct yes.